# Is there any email platform which allows mass mailing?

Tags: webapp-rec

We have a web applications which uses Gmail SMTP server to send email to users. But, Gmail has some sort of daily message quota restriction (like 2,000 messages/day).

Is there any other platform where we can send email without a need to worry about such limitation?

Comment: How many recipients is "mass"? Also does it need to be a 3rd-party service?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by platform ? Are you looking for product you will run on servers, framework/library to incorporate into own web app or 3rd party service ?

Comment: You need to clarify exactly what thresholds you want to send at.

Comment: Well, all I need is an SMTP server that I can use from within the web/windows applications. Capacity can easily be accumulated to 3000 messages in 24 hour period. 

In fact, that Gmail we use in our application right now is also used as a normal inbox by a human staff. So, we don't want it suspended.

Comment: I ended up using SendGrid. Its dashboard is quite good. Amazon SES is cheaper than SendGrid but it doesn't provide much information on activities.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Mailchimp this is one of the top email marketeers, and very easy to use .

http://www.mailchimp.com/

Answer (score 0):

2000 messages per day is a reasonable enough volume to get you blocked from the vast majority of Shared Web Hosts mail platforms, virtually guaranteed. They won't like you putting their Shared IP ranges at risk of being blocked. I can assure you that GMail, Yahoo, Hotmail et al blocking a Shared IP range is a massive pain in the behind - so I'm not hugely surprised that Gmail throw a fit too ... despite their size they'll suffer the same pain if other major ISP's start blocking their IP ranges.

What you need to do is look at third party solutions, there are a wealth of mass mail providers - most of them providing superb analytical detail on your mailshots, aswell as tools to help you evaluate how 'spammy' your message looks. You pay by the mail in most cases, so you should be able to find a solution which fits your budget.

A couple of examples which I have experience of, and can confirm are excellent platforms to work with are:

```
www.mailingmanager.co.uk - they offer a decent free trial to get used to it
www.streamsend.com - not used personally but heard good things from clients.
```

Also, this is probably stating the obvious but be very careful of who you are sending to. It doesn't matter how much money you throw at these companies, they will not tolerate spammers - make sure your lists are clean, legitimate and opt-in only. Buying in lists is tantamount to trying to smuggle the Devil into Heaven with most of these companies.

G'luck.

Comment: I'm aware of this IP blocking. And yeah, it seems the only way to go is to engage with mass mail providers as you suggested. I will take a look at those two providers (and mailchip as well, suggested by Scott). 

And, yep, our mailing list is legitimate and opt-in only.